# Swiper, React, Tailwind, Center Slide

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-swiper

Hey i try around last 3hr find what i do wrong with my code, i add Swiper, and try center my slides inside the box when i use justify-center on desktop media queries is working, but when i go smaller screen its stay on the right i write RIGHTHERE, idk what i do wrong i try and cant center slides inside the box on all media queries

```
import React from 'react';
import { Shape } from '../../../public/assets/svg';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { StarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { reviews } from '@/data/data';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Autoplay } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';

const ProductReviews = () => {
    return (
        <div className='relative py-6 flex justify-center z-30 max-w-6xl mx-auto'>
            <Swiper
                slidesPerView={1}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                centeredSlides={true}
                speed={1000}
                autoplay={{
                    delay: 4000,
                    disableOnInteraction: false,
                }}
                loop={true}
                grabCursor={true}
                modules={[Autoplay]}
                className='bg-white max-w-5xl'
            >
                {reviews.map((review) => (
                    <SwiperSlide key={review.id}>
                        <div className='RIGHTHERE flex items-center justify-center'>
                            <div className='bg-third h-96 sm:h-72 w-[256px] sm:w-[480px] lg:w-[640px] rounded-xl mt-16 relative z-50'>
                                <div className='hidden md:block absolute h-60 px-10 bg-third -left-16 top-5 rounded-xl'></div>
                                <div className='hidden lg:block absolute h-40 px-10 bg-third -left-28 top-16 rounded-xl'></div>
                                <div className='hidden md:block absolute h-60 px-10 bg-third -right-16 top-5 rounded-xl'></div>
                                <div className='hidden lg:block absolute h-40 px-10 bg-third -right-28 top-16 rounded-xl'></div>
                                <Shape className='absolute top-0 -left-32 md:-left-48 lg:-left-60 lg:top-12 w-32 h-32 z-10' />
                                <Shape className='absolute bottom-0 -right-32 md:-right-48 lg:-right-60 lg:bottom-12 w-32 h-32 z-10' />
                                <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center relative'>
                                    <div className='absolute -top-14'>
                                        <div className='rounded-full bg-third border-dashed border-2 border-myOrange p-2 relative'>
                                            <Image
                                                src={review.img}
                                                alt={review.imgAlt}
                                                width={96}
                                                height={96}
                                                className='rounded-full object-cover w-auto h-auto'
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className='pt-20 px-4 text-[14px] sm:text-base italic text-center'>
                                        {review.text}
                                    </p>
                                    <p className='mt-6 text-2xl font-oswald tracking-wider text-myOrange italic'>
                                        {review.name}
                                    </p>
                                    <p className='text-xs py-2 italic'>{review.position}</p>
                                    <div className='flex items-center  py-1'>
                                        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((rating) => (
                                            <StarIcon
                                                key={rating}
                                                className={`${
                                                    review.rating > rating
                                                        ? 'text-yellow-400'
                                                        : 'text-gray-200'
                                                }
                                        'h-3 w-3 flex-shrink-0'
                                        `}
                                                aria-hidden='true'
                                            />
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                ))}
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductReviews;
```